# Block a specific process to start for a given span of time

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement where I need a specific process eg: Notepad.exe to not be launched until all the new text files have been refreshed by a daily sync job. How can I block it till the sync happens?

My script is pretty basic

```
taskkill /f /IM "notepad.exe"
copy C:\tmp*.txt
C:\Target Folder\
```

I get file in use error because if which I have to restart the sync all over again after killing the process.

Comment: please share your script with us.

Comment: My script is pretty basic: taskkill /f /IM "notepad.exe", copy C:\tmp\*.txt , C:\Target Folder\

Comment: WHat can you tell us about the daily sync job? How is it launched, what does it do? Ultimately it has to give off some kind of signal to let you know that it's done.

Comment: Is it your script trying to launch Notepad, or something else?  PowerShell can't inject itself into a Windows `CreateProcess()` call, so the only practical thing you can do is delay the launching of the process.  If you really want to do something impractical, I guess there's always IFEO.

Comment: To clarify my above comment, @Curious it is necessary to know *what* is trying to launch Notepad.  That makes all the difference.  If your script is launching Notepad, then the question is about synchronization and inserting the appropriate delay.  If a 3rd process is launching Notepad, then your question is about code injection into the Windows kernel.

Comment: Rename notepad.exe to something else, rename it back when the sync is finished. If you can't rename it, change the ACLs on it so it's unreadable.